# JAVA StAX extracting

Tags: java, stax

I cannot figure out either how to extract the start tag element name within an XML file. I am close ~ meaning no errors and I am getting the tag name but I am getting the tag name plus information.
What I am getting is:

```
{http://www.publishing.org}author
{http://www.publishing.org}Date
{http://www.publishing.org}ISBN
```

My end result, I want my program to give me:

```
Author
Data
ISBN
```

First, here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookCatalog xmlns = "http://www.publishing.org">
    <Book>
        <Title>Yogasana</Title>
        <author>Dhirenda</author>
        <Date>1966</Date>
        <ISBN>81-40</ISBN>
        <Publisher>Dhirenda</Publisher>
        <Cost Currency = "INR">11.50</Cost>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Title>Yogasana</Title>
        <author>J. K</author>
        <Date>1954</Date>
        <ISBN>0-06</ISBN>
        <Publisher>Harper</Publisher>
        <Cost Currency = "INR">2.95</Cost>
    </Book>
</BookCatalog>
```

I have tried 
    System.out.println("Start Element GetName: " + se.getName());
    System.out.println("Start Element GetEventType: " + se.getEventType());
    System.out.println("Attribute name: " + attribute.getValue());
    System.out.println("Attribute name: " + attribute.getName());

The getname yields: {http://www.publishing.org}Date.

The getEventType yields: 1

The attribute.getValue yields: INR

The attribute.getName yields:Currency.

How do I get a result that is just the element name: Date, author ISBN, and so forth?

Why is the getName, which I believe is the correct method attaching the text: {http://www.publishing.org}?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    //System.out.println("Here");
    //String filename = null;
    String filename = "BookCatalog.xml";
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLEventReader reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(new FileReader(filename));

    String dataread = null;

    while(reader.hasNext())
            {
                XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
                XMLEvent nextEvent = reader.peek();
                switch (event.getEventType())
                        {
                    case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT:
                        StartElement se = event.asStartElement();

                        //StartElement se = (StartElement) event;
                        System.out.println("Start Element GetName: " + se.getName());
                        System.out.println("Start Element GetEventType: " + se.getEventType());

                        Iterator iterator = se.getAttributes();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                           Attribute attribute = (Attribute) iterator.next();
                            QName name = attribute.getName();
                            //String value = attribute.getValue();
                            //System.out.println("Attribute name/value: " + name + "/" + value);
                            //System.out.println("Attribute name: " + name);
                            System.out.println("Attribute Value: " + attribute.getValue());
                            System.out.println("Attribute name: " + attribute.getName());
                        }



                        //System.out.println("Here");
                        //System.out.print("<" + se.getName());

                        //System.out.print(" " + se.getName());
                        //Iterator iterator = se.getAttributes();
                        //System.out.print(" " + se.getAttributes());

                        System.out.printf("\n");
                        String elem = se.getName().toString();
                        //String elem = se.getAttributes().toString();
                        //String ele = event.getAttributeName();
                        //if( se.getName().toString() == "{http://www.publishing.org}Date")
                        if( se.getName().toString().equals("{http://www.publishing.org}Date"))
                        //if( elem == "1")
                        {
                         dataread = reader.getElementText();
                         //System.out.printf("data = %s\n",reader.getElementText());
                         System.out.printf("data = %s\n",dataread);

                        }
                        Iterator attributes = se.getNamespaces();

                        while(attributes.hasNext())
                        {
                            Attribute attr= (Attribute)attributes.next();
                            //System.out.print(" " + attr.getName() + "=\"" +attr.getValue() +"\"");
                            //System.out.printf("\n");
                        }//end while loop
                    //System.out.print(">");
                        if(nextEvent.isCharacters())
                        {
                            Characters c = reader.nextEvent().asCharacters();
                            if(!c.isWhiteSpace())
                            //System.out.print(c.getData());
                            System.out.printf("\n");
                        }// end if
                    /*case XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT>
                        EndElement ee = event.asEndElement();
                        System.out.print("</"+ee.getName()+">");
                        break;
                        * */
                        }// end witch
            }// end while
    System.out.printf("FINAL data = %s\n",dataread);

    reader.close();
}//end Main
```

}// public claSS

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) try

```
System.out.println("Start Element GetName: " + se.getName().getLocalPart());
```

2) XMLStreamReader could do the same job but faster

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: you've defined a namespace in your xml for BookCatalog

```
<BookCatalog xmlns = "http://www.publishing.org">
```

this is how you make the difference, if you have tags with the same name in different namespaces!

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can I get just the Date, ISBN and so forth with an XML that has a namespace? Thanks!